# Insert mysql com Ajax dentro do While

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estou tentando fazer um insert dinamico utilizando ajax.
como mostrado na imagem a baixo. Eu quero poder clicar em enviar de qualquer linha e realizar  os post referente a ela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso Fazer isso

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 20%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 1%;" class="center">Cod.</th>
        <th style="width: 18%;" >Produtos</th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 8%;">Valor</th>
        <th style="width: 5%;"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                 

  <?
    $cmd = "SELECT * FROM produtos where id_transfer = '1' limit 5";      
    $produtos = mysql_query($cmd)or die( mysql_error());
    $count=mysql_num_rows($produtos);
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {


 $id_produto = $linha['id_produtos'];
 $id_transfer = $linha['id_transfer'];
 $cheva = $linha['chave'];
?>                  


        <tr class="selectable">
        <td class="center"><input type="text" id="campo1" value="<?echo $id_transfer1?>" /></td>
        <td class="important"><input type="text"   id="campo2" value="<?echo "$id_produto"?>" /></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="text" id="campo3" value="<?echo $chave?>" /></td>
        <td class="center">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="inserir_registo()" /><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></i></a>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Veja se tem algo haver com o fato de ter um `$cheva = $linha['chave'];` e um `<?echo $chave?>`. Erro de digitação?

Comment: essa variável nem faz diferença. independente de qualquer variável que tiver só envia a pimeira linha do while digamos que a primeira linha tem id 1 a segunda 2 ......  só envia o id 1

Comment: Mas porque você não colocou apenas um botão de enviar? e os campos em formato array? Porque ai na hora de enviar, envia tudo de uma vez e grava os preenchidos...

Comment: Porque na verdade todos esses campos vão ficar hiddem, só vai aparecer os botões. porque isso , esse sistema vai ficar numa tela touch e eu queria que só clica-se  no item é ja inclui-se para a base

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na replicação de ID dos campos, isso não pode ocorrer.

Veja que dentro do seu `while` vc replica a propriedade ID de seus `input`. Os invés de fazer isso, coloque um ID por linha assim:

```
<% while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) { %>

<tr data-id="<%echo idDaLinha%>">
    <td><input type="text" name="campo1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="campo2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="campo3" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="botaoEnviar" data-id="<%echo idDaLinha%>">Enviar</button>
</tr>

<% } %>
```

E no seu jQuery:

```
$('.botaoEnviar').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var $tr = $('tr[data-id='+ id +']');

    var dadosAjax = 
    {
        campo1: $tr.find('input[name=campo1]').val(),
        campo2: $tr.find('input[name=campo2]').val(),
        campo3: $tr.find('input[name=campo3]').val()
    };

    // sua chamada ajax
});
```

Comment: Ola Tiago não tenho muito conhecimento de javascript  e não sei porque não consegui adaptar seu codigo no meu javascript.  não chamou o ajax

Comment: Montei o codigo assim https://jsfiddle.net/fabioo7/wcu6qkn8/  oque fiz de errado?

Comment: `<input type="button" class="botaoEnviar" data-id="<?echo idDaLinha?>">Enviar
</button>` Que isso mano ? Na linha 16 você abriu uma input e fechou com button